# MultipartFile#getContentType returns null during integration tests in Spring

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, spring-test

I have the following files:

**ImageForm.java:**

```
public class ImageForm {
  @FileNotEmpty
  private MultipartFile file;
  // other code ...
}
```

**GalleryController.java:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/galleries")
public class GalleryController {
@PostMapping("/{id}/image/create")
  public ModelAndView createImage(@PathVariable("id") long galleryId, @Valid ImageForm imageForm, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    // other code ...
    System.out.println(imageForm.getFile().getContentType()); // Prints: null
    // other code ...
  }
}
```

**GalleryControllerIT.java:**

```
@SqlGroup({
     @Sql("classpath:test-schema.sql"),
     @Sql("classpath:test-gallery-data.sql"),
     @Sql("classpath:test-image-data.sql")
})
public class GalleryControllerIT extends SetupControllerIT {
    @Test
    public void createImage_POSTHttpMethod_ImageIsCreated() throws Exception {
        Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test-image.png").toURI());
        byte[] image = Files.readAllBytes(path);

        mvc.perform(
            multipart("/admin/galleries/1/image/create")
                .file("file", image) // TODO: ImageForm.file.contentType is null.
                .with(csrf())
        ).andExpect(status().isFound());

        assertThat(imageRepository.count(), is(5L));
    }
}
```

1. In test `GallerControllerIT#createImage_POSTHttpMethod_ImageIsCreated`
   I set a file.
2. The test sends the file to `GalleryController#createImage` and maps it 
   to `ImageForm#file` attribute.
3. `ImageForm#file` is of type `MultipartFile` which has method `getContentType`.
4. The method `MultipartFile#getContentType` returns `null`.

The question is, why does the `MultipartFile#getContentType` return null? It works correctly when outside of test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For full data you should call

```
.file(new MockMultipartFile("image", "some_name", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, image))
```

Because under hood in your case if you call `.file("file", image)` they call short version of constructor `MockMultipartFile` without content type

`MockMvc` trying to not create or declare some additional values or parameters if you are not declare their.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.